# Ispconfig 3.1.13p1 problem creating new Let's encrypt certificate. Multiple accounts

Tags: lets-encrypt, ispconfig, ispconfig-3

I've an Ubuntu 16.04 server with ISPConfig 3.1.13p1. Lately I created a new website and I checked "Let's Encrypt" and "SSL" as usual.
However, after few minutes the setting was removed. I guessed it was a problem in creating the certificate.
The domain DNS are ok, but I found these logs:

```
2020-05-28 18:25:02,145:DEBUG:certbot.main:Arguments: ['-n', '--text', '--agree-tos', '--expand', '--authenticator', 'webroot', '--server', 'https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory', '--rsa-key-size', '4096', '--email', 'postmaster@mydomain.it', '--domains', 'mydomain.it', '--domains', 'www.mydomain.it', '--webroot-path', '/usr/local/ispconfig/interface/acme']
2020-05-28 18:25:02,145:DEBUG:certbot.main:Discovered plugins: PluginsRegistry(PluginEntryPoint#manual,PluginEntryPoint#null,PluginEntryPoint#standalone,PluginEntryPoint#webroot)
2020-05-28 18:25:02,154:DEBUG:certbot.log:Root logging level set at 20
2020-05-28 18:25:02,155:INFO:certbot.log:Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
2020-05-28 18:25:02,156:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.selection:Requested authenticator webroot and installer None
2020-05-28 18:25:02,156:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.selection:Single candidate plugin: * webroot
Description: Place files in webroot directory
Interfaces: IAuthenticator, IPlugin
Entry point: webroot = certbot.plugins.webroot:Authenticator
Initialized: <certbot.plugins.webroot.Authenticator object at 0x7f97a49f0400>
Prep: True
2020-05-28 18:25:02,157:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.selection:Selected authenticator <certbot.plugins.webroot.Authenticator object at 0x7f97a49f0400> and installer None
2020-05-28 18:25:02,157:INFO:certbot.plugins.selection:Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None
2020-05-28 18:25:02,201:DEBUG:certbot.log:Exiting abnormally:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/letsencrypt", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('certbot==0.31.0', 'console_scripts', 'certbot')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 1365, in main
    return config.func(config, plugins)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 1234, in certonly
    le_client = _init_le_client(config, auth, installer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 605, in _init_le_client
    acc, acme = _determine_account(config)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 513, in _determine_account
    acc = display_ops.choose_account(accounts)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/display/ops.py", line 86, in choose_account
    "Please choose an account", labels, force_interactive=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/display/util.py", line 507, in menu
    self._interaction_fail(message, cli_flag, "Choices: " + repr(choices))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/display/util.py", line 469, in _interaction_fail
    raise errors.MissingCommandlineFlag(msg)
certbot.errors.MissingCommandlineFlag: Missing command line flag or config entry for this setting:
Please choose an account
Choices: ['web1.localdomain@2019-04-04T14:30:30Z (7c2a)', 'my.server.com@2017-03-05T02:16:08Z (f1b3)']
```

Searching for a similar error, I found [this post](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/please-choose-an-account/17262/2): I can confirm to have 2 directory in /etc/letsencrypt: acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org and acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org

How can I fix the script used from ISPConfig in order to get the certificate for this new domain?

Comment: I'd try updating certbot and ISPconfig first.

The next ISPconfig reload (3.1.16) will also have support for acme.sh as an alternative to certbot. See https://git.ispconfig.org/ispconfig/ispconfig3/-/issues/5461 for that.